# Time complexity of this mutual recursive code

Tags: java, performance, recursion, big-o, time-complexity

I have this mutual recursive code in java, i wonder what is the time complexity of this code. My guess is O(2^n) though, since for the G method, return (n-1) + G(n-1) splits into 2 during each call.Or is this part O(n)? I am not sure about this.

```
public static int F(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
        return n + F(n/2);
    else
        return G(n-1)-n;
}

public static int G(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
        return F(n-1) + G(n-1);
    else
        return F(n-3);
}
```

Comment: Would it be something more like (n!)?

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite G in terms of F.

```
public static int G(int n) {
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else if(n % 2 == 0)
        return F(n-1) + F(n-4);
    else
        return F(n-3);
}
```

This lets you rewrite F in terms of F.

```
public static int F(int n) {
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else if(n % 2 == 0)
        return n + F(n/2);
    else
        return F(n-2) + F(n-5);
}
```

The result is O(n): O(F(n)) for the case when n % 2 == 0 is log(n), which means that O(F(n)) when n % 2 != 0 is O(n) + O(log(n)), or simply **O(n)**